# Virtualbox gateway connection

Tags: networking, virtualbox, gateway

Is it possible to make a "gateway" computer, which will be connected to Internet and other three guests machines, which would be able to reach web through first PC? I don't want these machines to be in bridged connection - I want this gw machine to act as some kind of router.

EDIT: I am running Ubuntu Server on every vm.

[image: Network topology diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, configure two Ethernet for the "gateway" one as Bridged Adapter with the host and another as Internal Network, after this the other VMs with a only nick attached to the Internal Network.

You can use pfsense for the gateway VMs if you do not want manage iptables via command line or any router/firewall distribution.

The Bridged interface access to the world:
[image: The Bridged interface access to the world]

The internal network interface with a name for the switch:
[image: The internal network interface with a name for the switch]

The VM attached to the same Internal Network:
[image: The VM attached to the same Internal Network]

Comment: Alright, but I still have to configure second adapter manualy, right?
I have edited /etc/network/interfaces file with following config:
https://imgur.com/a/FteMsSW
and it seems to be okay under ifconfig https://imgur.com/a/nUrG0dO
but now I am not able to reach external sites (seems like machine tries to ping address from secondary adapter)
https://imgur.com/a/dAU36Ld